# Name of internally lit translucent carved art

Tags: terminology

What is the name of the art form where a translucent material (could be cylindrical) is carved on the inside and lit from within so the image is rendered in brightness determined by how thick the remaining material is?

Comment: Do you have an image of an example?

Comment: You can read on some guidelines and suggestions for these types of questions [here on Meta](http://meta.crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/212/what-guidelines-should-we-set-for-identification-style-questions)

Comment: Like this? http://img-cdn.jg.jugem.jp/706/2363597/20120521_531643.jpg

Comment: @CreationEdge You think he is describing glass carving?

Comment: Sounds sort of like those fancy Halloween pumpkin carvings that don't carve all the way through the pumpkin flesh.

Comment: Actually @CreationEdge the first thing I though of was those himalayan salt lamps but I don't know if they're ever carved very intricately.

Comment: Sorry, no images except the mental one of an instance I saw at the Madison hackerspace a year ago.  That one might have been 3D printed.

Comment: The carved and/or edge lit owl image is not what I mean.  The pumpkin reference from @Catija is the right stuff.
I guess I should send a note to the hackerspace - thanks for that inspiration!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With thanks to Chris Meyer from Sector67:

It's **[lithophane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithophane)**.

Sorry I wasn't clever enough to check with the source in the first place, but thanks for asking the question that triggered that!

Comment: I'm glad you found this -- I _have_ a lithophane sitting on my shelf at home, but couldn't remember what it's called, and googling was getting me nowhere. Well done.

Comment: Thanks. I was also pretty surprised that googling such a narrow, specific topic with the best words I could throw at it didn't turn up an answer.  Glad to throw a little light on (behind?) this one.

Comment: FYI, you can mark your own answer as the correct one by clicking the checkmark :)